# Optimization - Leveraging Browser cache not working for .js and .png

Tags: .htaccess, caching, optimization, browser-cache, google-pagespeed

Im optimizing a web site and i cant leverage browser caching for .js and .png files.

My .htaccess looks like this:

```
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xhtml+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/rss+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/vnd.ms-fontobject
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-opentype
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-otf
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-truetype
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-ttf
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE font/opentype
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE font/otf
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE font/ttf


  <ifModule mod_expires>
 ExpiresActive On
 ExpiresDefault "access plus 5 days"
 ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access plus 2592000 seconds"
 ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 2592000 seconds"
 ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 60 days"
 ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 2592000 seconds"
 ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access plus 2592000 seconds"
 ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 604800 seconds"
 ExpiresByType text/javascript "access plus 1 year"
 ExpiresByType text/x-javascript "access plus 1 year"
 ExpiresByType application/javascript "access plus 1 year"
 ExpiresByType application/x-javascript "access plus 1 year"
 ExpiresByType text/html "access plus 600 seconds"
 ExpiresByType application/xhtml+xml "access plus 600 seconds"
 <FilesMatch "\.(bmp|css|flv|gif|ico|jpg|jpeg|js|pdf|png|svg|swf|tif|tiff)$">
        Header set Last-Modified "Mon, 31 Aug 2015 00:00:00 GMT"
    </FilesMatch>
 </ifModule>
```

Caching seems to work with other files but most of analyzing tools show error messages like this for the pngs:

[image: png error message]

or this for Javascript files:
[image]

I tried adding an unsetting the last-modified header via .htaccess and various .htaccess configurations but nothing seems to happen. I have to mention my hosting provider is using cloudflare on a virtual machine. What am i doing wrong?